# Unknown error while authenticating user through angular 8 client

Tags: .net, angular, api

Getting unknown error when connecting to web API call through angular.

I tried everything, it's working in postman but not with angular 8 on my localhost

```
login(username: string, password: string) {const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders(
        { 
            "Authorization": "Basic " ,
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
           'content-type':'application/json'
        })
    }
//return this.http.post<any>(`${config.apiUrl}/users/authenticate`, { username, password })
   return this.https.post<any>(`https://localhost:53595/api/users/authenticate`, { username, password },httpOptions )
        .pipe(
            map(user => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response

            if (user && user.token) {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                this.currentUserSubject.next(user);

            }


            return user;
        }));
}
```

Comment: can you explain `Getting unknown error` or post detailed error here

Comment: Is it CORS error??

Comment: Is the back-end .net core or before?

Comment: yes .NET core 2.1

Answer (score 0):

As you said its working from **Postman** and not from **Localhost** then I suspect its **CORS error**, [About CORS](https://daveceddia.com/access-control-allow-origin-cors-errors-in-angular/).

You must be getting something like this.

> No Access-Control-Allow-Origin

This means the origin you are hosting you app on is not allowed to make any request to server.

As per my knowledge,This error needs to be handled from the **Server/API** end.

Or you can disable it using chrome extension you can get it [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en).

---

More Info on how to handle CORS on different servers as follows :

[PHP Server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control)

[.NET Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

[JAVA Server](https://howtodoinjava.com/servlets/java-cors-filter-example/)

Comment: it looks like CORs error and i am working on it. let me seed this will resolve it, yes after debug and attached to chrome i am getting specific error Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44317/api/users/authenticate' from origin 'http://localhost:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. [http://localhost:5000/login?returnUrl=%2F]
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED [https://localhost:44317/api/users/authenticate]

Comment: Updated answer with few links. Please follow them to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

if it is .net core go in Startup.cs and serve both back-end and front-end with https and enable CORS

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...
      services.AddCors();
...
}


   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
   {
    ...
      app.UseCors(builder =>
            builder.WithOrigins("YOUR_FRONTEND_URL")
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowCredentials());
    ...
    }
```

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: yes i had already had "services.add cores" ,but i added the front end url as per your suggestion to my web api and now that error is gone but still i am not getting my USER Data , i will check but Thanks for so far i ad progress